# How to include custom font in e-mail not found on website?

Tags: css, font-face

I created a font of my handwriting that I wish to be able to use in e-mails. I read up on CSS, and found that you can use @font-face to specify custom fonts found online that you want to use in your e-mail. However, my font isn't found anywhere online, and it doesn't seem to work just using the google drive or dropbox links. My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: MyDumbFont;
    src: url(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jd3o49BW07_3FNihjipRbblQ1gP7Sady
}

div {
    font-family: MyDumbFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> Please work. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I alternatively also tried using the Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0cvl2rcut640sc/Myfont-Regular.otf?dl=0\

It seems like these links don't allow the font to open properly. Is this the case, or am I making some stupid formatting issue?

I've never really used HTML and CSS before today, so it may be that I made some kind of formatting/syntax mistake. I was told to make this for work, but this coding type of stuff is not normally in my purview (It's a rather small business and I'm just the guy who's "good with computers".)

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: afaik you can not use custom fonts in emails.

Comment: Well for starters you're missing the closing bracket `)` in your `src`. I'm also not sure about the logistics of using a service like DropBox to host a file that you're referencing directly, as they add their own wrapper (meaning you can't access the 'file'). You'll want a **direct** file link.

Comment: You should create a public repository on Github, it's easier to get the raw file from there than GDrive or Dropbox

Comment: @RobertHare This is an article I found here on Stack Overflow that talks about your situation and it sounds a little complicated to me, so I would try to do something like Alberto suggested and make it easier on yourself.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, @AlbertoAnderickJr I'm going to try to put the font file on github and will update post with results. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The general rules for HTML/CSS don't apply to e-mail. Lots of the features are not available, including scripts and (in most clients) the entire use of the `<style>` tag. Btw, dropbox also does allow direct links to public files, so moving to GitHub won't solve it. Neither service should be used as a file host or CDN by the way.

Comment: See [Using Web Fonts in Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/) for good info on custom web fonts and see [Webfont support in email](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/) for a breakdown of which email clients support web fonts.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create custom styles and formatting using XML in an MSOutlook signature, but outside of this it's generally ill-advised to try and use custom HTML/CSS/Fonts, or other markup in e-mails because the vast majority of e-mail is stripped of superfluous code to prevent attacks.

Most e-mail prevents HTML/CSS in the message body from being displayed, and the same goes for images a high percentage of the time.

Also -- and I could be wrong here -- but I don't know that Dropbox or Google Drive will want you trying to effectively use them as a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't allow Cross-Origin Requests via the URL you mentioned. If you replace the `www.` with `dl.` you get a link which does.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gqov0rmu/6/

Maybe think about buying some webspace for your files, because Dropbox and GoogleDrive are not made for this.